# 500 Internal Server Error: ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to create a back up server using LAMP configuration. I installed everything and pushed my already running code from main server to the new server. The code on the main server works great, however, when I run it on the new server, a few pages show me 500 Internal server.

I checked the php.ini configuration and found that `short_open_tag = On`. On checking the web logs, this is what I found, can someone please help on how to overcome this.

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: token in /var/www/html/Includes/session.php on line 10 [Wed Mar 30 07:50:20.077006 2016] [:error] [pid 24161] [client 2620:10d:c0e1:5003:6911:8c70:8351:a252:60467] PHP Notice: Undefined index: expire in /var/www/html/Includes/session.php on line 11 [Wed Mar 30 07:50:20.077018 2016] [:error] [pid 24161] [client 2620:10d:c0e1:5003:6911:8c70:8351:a252:60467] PHP Notice: Undefined index: expire in /var/www/html/Includes/session.php on line 20

Please note that the code works excellent on main server

Edit:

```
Line 10: $token = $_SESSION["token"];
Line 11 $expire = $_SESSION["expire"];
Line 20 if(time() > $_SESSION["expire"]) {
```

Comment: Post the line of code that return errors

Comment: posted as per advise

Comment: Most likely that system uses a newer version of php which is more picky. The issue at hand simply is that you try to access `$_SESSION["token"]` which is not set. If you did restore the session (as is indicated by the fact that things work fine on the other system), then most likely you just have to add some simply test before accessing such array elements. Something like: `$token = isset($_SESSION["token"]) ? $_SESSION["token"] : null;` This obviously assumes that this token is not mandatory for the script. Otherwise something must be really wrong, you have to dig deeper then.

Comment: Did you use `session_start();` at the beginning of the file ?

Comment: @LorenzoBelfanti yes, I used `session_start();` at the beginning of file

Comment: have you migrated to a load balanced server?

Comment: please, do a `print_r($_SESSION); die;` before accessing the token to clearly see what your session contains before accessing its contents. This sentence helps you to **debug** php.